# Ansible Jinja2 Список и словари - переменная внутри переменной

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Не удаётся реализовать шаблон jinja2 для ansible. Проблема такая- есть список(примерно):

```
server:
  - host1
  - host2
  - host3
```

и есть словари, имена которых совпадают со значениями в списках:

```
host1:
   my_option1: 1
   my_option2: 2
```

Нужно вызвать цикл по значениям из списка, а в соответствии со значениями подставить все данные из словаря, если имя словаря совпадает со значением из списка.
Пример результата

```
host1:
   my_option1: 1
   my_option2: 2
```

Мне не удаётся такая комбинация:

```
{% for a in servers}
{{a}}:
{% for b in {{a}} %}
 {{b.my_option1}}
 {{b.my_option2}}
{{% endfor %}
{{% endfor %}
```

Синтаксис не даёт возможность переопределить заново {{a}} и вызвать значения из словаря.
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Решение примерно такое

```
{% for a in server %}
[{{a}}]
{% for b in my_servers %}
{% if a == b %}
option1: {{my_servers[b].option1}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Словарь пришлось переделать на вид такой:

```
my_servers:
 host1:
  option1:1
  option2:2
```